# Stepwise regression

Tags: machine-learning

I think that both forward selection and backward selection should give the same results if the evaluation model is deterministic and using the same variables gives the same results. Is this true? If so, what are the reasons for chosing one method over the other?

Comment: Why do you think this?  I don't see any reason to expect them to give the same results.

Comment: @D.W. There is one set with max value so forward will add variables until it reaches it and backward will remove variables until it reaches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not true.  There is no guarantee that they will give the same results.  They are a heuristic.  Neither one is guaranteed to find the optimal subset of features, and they might produce two different subsets.

For instance, the effectiveness of a set of features might depend in some nonlinear and complicated way on the particular set you choose.  So, in general, the problem is just the general optimization problem of finding a set $S \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ that maximizes $f(S)$, where $f$ is some function (here, the accuracy of the model on a cross-validation set).  Since $f$ can be arbitrary, forward selection and backward selection can give different results, and neither is guaranteed to yield the optimal set of features.

Comment: Even if they use the same deterministic evaluation function?

Comment: @juyt, yes, that's right.

Comment: OK, thank you. I have done some examples and I have found that behaviour in all of them, but they are only examples.